# Dealing with Pull Requests in Nested Forks: Repo A, Repo B (which is a Fork of A)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

A github `repo A` is a fork of another github `repo B`. I want to be able to write pull requests in both, especially since both repos have evolved apart and have different qualities. But I can only create a total of one fork for both repos together.

## In detail:

After I made a fork of `repo B` and successfully got a PR from there as well, I wanted to write a similar PR for `repo A`.
But when I try to create a fork on `repo A` to be able to write a PR on it, I get the message: "Existing forks
username/forkB"
And I can't create a new fork there.

I am working in VSCode and would like to know how to do this in VSCode.

After forking `repo B`, there is now a branch `main` in my  `repo B fork`, as well as two branches for PullRequests on `repo B fork`.
I suppose it should be possible within the structure of Git / Github to now also get a branch of `repo A main` from which I can fork PRs for `repo A`, but I haven't understood yet how to do that. Of course, both (`repo A main` and `repo B main`) should be provided with clearly distinguishing names, so that it remains clearly recognizable to which repo they now belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add a 3rd remote of `Fork A` using the VSCode menu and searching for it.

[image: Image showing Add Remote git menu in vscode]

Or you can easily add via the cli.

```bash
git remote add RepoA https://github.com/RepoAOrg/Repo.git
```

It will result in having 3 remotes in you local git repo. I would rename them to help keep organized instead of going with the common `origin` and `upstream`.

`origin`: `https://github.com/YourName/Repo.git`
`RepoB`: `https://github.com/ForkBOrg/Repo.git`
`RepoA`: `http://github.com/ForkAOrg/Repo.git`

And you will most likely need to rebase your feature branches to the relevant target of `Fork A` while resolving conflicts due to the divergent main line like you stated.